# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "raster" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango, postgis-raster

my models: I have created 3 models here and When I migrate then I get the error.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import RasterField

class WorldBorder(models.Model):
    # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
    # world borders shapefile.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()

    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Zipcode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5) 
    poly= models.PolygonField()

class Elevation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    rast = RasterField(srid=2346)
```

my settings .. The database I used is Postgres so that I can use postgis for geodjango

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis",
    "NAME": "django_course",
    "USER": "postgres",
    "PASSWORD": "**************",
    "HOST": "localhost",
    "PORT": "5432",
}
}
```

Comment: Does your database have `PostGIS` installed?

Comment: @JimJones it does have postgis installed is the problem because of postgres version??

Comment: Can you post what you get from this function in postgres? `SELECT PostGIS_Version()`

Comment: @JimJones I got this 3.0 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: @JimJones That totally worked . Can you please explain me how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the [`PostGIS Raster`](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3-separate-raster-extension) extension. Create the extension and try again:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
```

Quote from the [`documentation`](https://postgis.net/2019/10/20/postgis-3.0.0/):

> Note that a major change in 3.0 is that the raster functionality has
>   been broken out as a **separate extension**.

Answer (score 3):

Add these two lines to your migrations file *elevation_zipcode.py*:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension

operations = [
        CreateExtension('postgis_raster'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your database setting

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'database_name',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'USER': 'user_name',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: It is encouraged to provide a description of how your answer solves the problem.