# PostGIS returns record as datatype. This is unexpected

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have this query

```
WITH buffered AS (
    SELECT 
        ST_Buffer(geom , 10, 'endcap=round join=round') AS geom,
        id
    FROM line),
hexagons AS (
    SELECT 
        ST_HexagonGrid(10, buffered.geom) AS hex,
        buffered.id
    FROM buffered
) SELECT * FROM hexagons;
```

This gives the `datatype` `record` in the column `hex`. This is unexpected. I expect `geometry` as a `datatype`. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_HexagonGrid.html), the function `ST_HexagonGrid` returns a `setof record`. These records contain however a `geometry` attribute called `geom`, so in order to access the `geometry` of this `record` you have to wrap the variable with parenthesis `()` and call the attribute with a dot `.`, e.g.

```
SELECT (hex).geom FROM hexagons;
```

or just access fetch all attributes using `*` (in this case, `i`,`j` and `geom`):

```
SELECT (hex).* FROM hexagons;
```

Demo (**PostGIS 3.1**):

```
WITH j (hex) AS (
 SELECT 
  ST_HexagonGrid(
   10,ST_Buffer('LINESTRING(-105.55 41.11,-115.48 37.16,-109.29 29.38,-98.34 27.13)',1))    
)
SELECT ST_AsText((hex).geom,2) FROM j;

                                       st_astext                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((-130 34.64,-125 25.98,-115 25.98,-110 34.64,-115 43.3,-125 43.3,-130 34.64))
 POLYGON((-115 25.98,-110 17.32,-100 17.32,-95 25.98,-100 34.64,-110 34.64,-115 25.98))
 POLYGON((-115 43.3,-110 34.64,-100 34.64,-95 43.3,-100 51.96,-110 51.96,-115 43.3))
 POLYGON((-100 34.64,-95 25.98,-85 25.98,-80 34.64,-85 43.3,-95 43.3,-100 34.64))
```

As `ST_HexagonGrid` returns a `setof record`, you can access the record atributes using a `LATERAL` as described [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300557/2275388), or just call the function in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT i,j,ST_AsText(geom,2) FROM 
  ST_HexagonGrid(
   10,ST_Buffer('LINESTRING(-105.55 41.11,-115.48 37.16,-109.29 29.38,-98.34 27.13)',1));

 i  | j |                                       st_astext                                        
----+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -8 | 2 | POLYGON((-130 34.64,-125 25.98,-115 25.98,-110 34.64,-115 43.3,-125 43.3,-130 34.64))
 -7 | 1 | POLYGON((-115 25.98,-110 17.32,-100 17.32,-95 25.98,-100 34.64,-110 34.64,-115 25.98))
 -7 | 2 | POLYGON((-115 43.3,-110 34.64,-100 34.64,-95 43.3,-100 51.96,-110 51.96,-115 43.3))
 -6 | 2 | POLYGON((-100 34.64,-95 25.98,-85 25.98,-80 34.64,-85 43.3,-95 43.3,-100 34.64))
```

Further reading: [`How to divide world into cells (grid)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300557/2275388)

Comment: By the way: Do you know what `i` and `j` are?

Comment: @Stophface as far as I understand they represent row and column indexes, which together creates an identifier for each cell.