# Problem with indexing time series data, filtering is too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to query a total of 46M rows and still not sure what index to use for this data, here my table looks like this;

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "data" (
    "deviceId" UUID,
    "eventDate" DATE,
    "eventHour" SMALLINT,
    "eventTime" TIME(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    "point" GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326),
    "city_code" INTEGER,
    "county_code" INTEGER,
    "district_code" INTEGER,
    "duration" INTEGER,
    "deviceType" TEXT,
    "cell" H3INDEX,
    "yas" SMALLINT,
    "ses" SMALLINT,
    PRIMARY KEY ("deviceId", "eventDate", "eventTime")
);
```

I do not need to filter rows by device ID, I am looking to filter rows by `cell` mainly, cell represents what cell this point is in and looks something like this on map:
[image]

Cells are basically text data type and has values similar to `8c2d1c68a2d07ff` and fixed length.

Basically I need to group the rows (points) by cells and filter them by `yas`, `ses` and `eventTime (in hourly basis and between date ranges)`. `yas` and `ses` are category type of data, integers will be limited to only 1-10 representing different categories. I have tried these indexes but takes more than 1 second to compute for 46M rows and there will be 10x more rows than that:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_cell" ON "data" ("cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_ses_cell" ON "data" ("ses", "cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_yas_cell" ON "data" ("yas", "cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_date_cell" ON "data" ("eventDate", "cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_date_cell" ON "data" ("eventTime", "cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_date_cell" ON "data" ("eventHour", "cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_date_time_cell" ON "data" ("eventHour", "eventDate", "cell") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

And here is a sample query and query planner result:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH ref AS (
    SELECT refcell, h3_cell_to_children(refcell, 12) node
    FROM (
            SELECT h3_polygon_to_cells(ST_SetSRID(
                    ST_MakeBox2D(
                            ST_Point(28.93155097961426, 40.97555652808213),
                            ST_Point(29.058237075805668, 41.029513890837386)
                    ), 4326
            ), 8) refcell
    ) as cells
), filtered AS (
    SELECT cell, count(*)
    FROM data
    WHERE
        "cell" IN (SELECT node FROM ref) AND
        "eventDate" BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-01' AND
        "ses" = ANY(ARRAY[0]) AND
        "yas" = ANY(ARRAY[0,1,2])
    GROUP BY cell
)

SELECT refcell, sum(count)
FROM (
    SELECT refcell, node, count
    FROM ref, filtered
    WHERE cell = ref.node
) as t
GROUP BY refcell;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=500785.48..500787.98 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=1322.053..1322.064 rows=60 loops=1)
   Group Key: ref.refcell
   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 48kB
   CTE ref
     ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5022.77 rows=1000000 width=16) (actual time=173.051..184.126 rows=187278 loops=1)
           ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=173.043..173.108 rows=78 loops=1)
                 ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=172.681..172.682 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=159082.09..181762.72 rows=62800000 width=16) (actual time=1297.852..1321.680 rows=3705 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (ref.node = filtered.cell)
         ->  CTE Scan on ref  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=16) (actual time=173.053..186.193 rows=187278 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=158925.09..158925.09 rows=12560 width=16) (actual time=1124.736..1124.737 rows=3705 loops=1)
               Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 302kB
               ->  Subquery Scan on filtered  (cost=158673.89..158925.09 rows=12560 width=16) (actual time=1123.696..1124.310 rows=3705 loops=1)
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=158673.89..158799.49 rows=12560 width=16) (actual time=1123.694..1124.116
rows=3705 loops=1)
                           Group Key: data.cell
                           Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 913kB
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=22500.56..156950.74 rows=344630 width=8) (actual time=91.799..1111.033 rows=91725 loops=1)
                                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=22500.00..22502.00 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=91.473..137.551 rows=187278 loops=1)
                                       Group Key: ref_1.node
                                       Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 11073kB  Disk Usage: 3472kB
                                       ->  CTE Scan on ref ref_1  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual tim
e=0.001..42.754 rows=187278 loops=1)
                                 ->  Index Scan using data_ses_cell on data  (cost=0.56..671.69 rows=55 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=0 loops=187278)
                                       Index Cond: ((ses = ANY ('{0}'::integer[])) AND (cell = ref_1.node))
                                       Filter: (("eventDate" >= '2023-01-01'::date) AND ("eventDate" <= '2023-02-01'::date) AND (yas = ANY ('{0,1,2}'::integer[])))
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.273 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 41
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.609 ms, Inlining 7.226 ms, Optimization 107.961 ms, Emission 62.515 ms, Total 180.311 ms
 Execution Time: 1325.916 ms
(31 rows)
```

Server specs are `64GB Ram`, `Ryzen 5 3600` and `512GB NVMe ssd`.

I at least need to execute this kind of query under 500ms time. Is it possible?

Should I continue to use PostgreSQL at the first place for that many rows? Or if postgresql can handle that many data points, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**
I have changed structure a bit and this is the final state:

New indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_ses_cell" ON "data" ("cell", "ses", "yas") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_date_time_cell" ON "data" USING BRIN ("eventTime") WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) WITH ref AS (
    SELECT refcell, h3_cell_to_children(refcell, 12) node
    FROM (
        SELECT h3_polygon_to_cells(ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakeBox2D(
                    ST_Point(28.87567520141602, 40.95903013727966),
                    ST_Point(29.12904739379883, 41.06692773019345)
                ), 4326
        ), 9) refcell
    ) as cells
), filtered AS (
        SELECT cell, count(*)
        FROM data
        WHERE "cell" IN (SELECT node FROM ref) AND "eventTime"::DATE BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-01' AND "ses" = ANY(ARRAY[0]) AND "yas" = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])
        GROUP BY cell
)

SELECT refcell, sum(count)
FROM (
    SELECT refcell, node, count
    FROM ref, filtered
    WHERE cell = ref.node
) as t
GROUP BY refcell;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=144023.36..144025.86 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4356.905..4356.967 rows=431 loops=1)
   Group Key: ref.refcell
   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 173kB
   Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=6321 written=8197
   I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=7.378 write=24.451
   CTE ref
     ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5022.77 rows=1000000 width=16) (actual time=1.766..48.559 rows=750827 loops=1)
           ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=1.764..2.680 rows=2189 loops=1)
                 ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=72494.97..95175.59 rows=8765000 width=16) (actual time=4245.857..4356.724 rows=858 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (ref.node = filtered.cell)
         Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=6321 written=8197
         I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=7.378 write=24.451
         ->  CTE Scan on ref  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=16) (actual time=1.767..54.292 rows=750827 loops=1)
               Buffers: temp read=2383 written=1
               I/O Timings: temp read=2.751 write=0.028
         ->  Hash  (cost=72473.06..72473.06 rows=1753 width=16) (actual time=4244.035..4244.037 rows=858 loops=1)
               Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 57kB
               Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=3938 written=8196
               I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=4.627 write=24.423
               ->  Subquery Scan on filtered  (cost=72424.85..72473.06 rows=1753 width=16) (actual time=4243.319..4243.933 rows=858 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=3938 written=8196
                     I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=4.627 write=24.423
                     ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=72424.85..72455.53 rows=1753 width=16) (actual time=4243.318..4243.873 rows=858 loops=1)
                           Group Key: data.cell
                           Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=3938 written=8196
                           I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=4.627 write=24.423
                           ->  Sort  (cost=72424.85..72429.23 rows=1753 width=8) (actual time=4243.313..4243.460 rows=4456 loops=1)
                                 Sort Key: data.cell
                                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 193kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=3938 written=8196
                                 I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=4.627 write=24.423
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=22500.56..72330.40 rows=1753 width=8) (actual time=330.563..4242.929 rows=4456 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724, temp read=3938 written=8196
                                       I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652, temp read=4.627 write=24.423
                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=22500.00..22502.00 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=326.702..602.036 rows=750827 loops=1)
                                             Group Key: ref_1.node
                                             Batches: 21  Memory Usage: 11073kB  Disk Usage: 19600kB
                                             Buffers: temp read=3938 written=8196
                                             I/O Timings: temp read=4.627 write=24.423
                                             ->  CTE Scan on ref ref_1  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.000..183.769 rows=750827 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: temp written=2382
                                                   I/O Timings: temp write=9.866
                                       ->  Index Scan using data_ses_cell on data  (cost=0.56..249.13 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=750827)
                                             Index Cond: ((cell = ref_1.node) AND (ses = ANY ('{0}'::integer[])) AND (yas = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[])))
                                             Filter: ((("eventTime")::date >= '2023-01-01'::date) AND (("eventTime")::date <= '2023-01-01'::date))
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                             Buffers: shared hit=8999147 read=304826 dirtied=32 written=11724
                                             I/O Timings: shared/local read=476.680 write=29.652
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=29
 Planning Time: 0.305 ms
 Execution Time: 4361.263 ms
(53 rows)
```

---

**EDIT 2**

We have added a month of data and there is now total 200M rows.

I changed the table a bit and indexes;

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "data" (
    device_id UUID,                                             -- Indicates the device ID
    event_time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,    -- Event Time
    city_code INTEGER,                                      -- City Code
    county_code INTEGER,                                    -- County Code
    district_code INTEGER,                              -- District Code
    -- point GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326),                 -- Point (lon, lat)
    duration INTEGER,                                           -- Duration (seconds)
    num_pings SMALLINT,                                     -- Number of pings
    cell TEXT,                                                      -- Cell (H3)
    yas SMALLINT,                                                   -- Age
    ses SMALLINT                                                    -- Socio-Economic Status
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_event_time_idx" ON "data" (event_time);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_event_time_idx" ON "data" using brin (event_time);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_cell_idx" ON "data" (cell);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "data_ses_yas_event_time_cell_idx" ON "data" (ses, yas, event_time, cell);
```

Current status:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) WITH ref AS (
    SELECT refcell::text, h3_cell_to_children(refcell, 12)::text node
    FROM (
        SELECT h3_polygon_to_cells(ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakeBox2D(
                    ST_Point(28.96532535552979, 41.01392390972017),
                    ST_Point(28.981161117553714, 41.020667069908704)
            ), 4326
        ), 12) refcell
    ) as cells
), filtered AS (
    SELECT cell, count(*)
    FROM data
    WHERE
        "cell" IN (SELECT node FROM ref) AND
        "event_time" BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-01' AND
        "ses" = ANY(ARRAY[0]) AND
        "yas" = ANY(ARRAY[0,1,2])
    GROUP BY cell
)

SELECT refcell, sum(count)
FROM (
    SELECT refcell, node, count
    FROM ref, filtered
    WHERE cell = ref.node
) as t
GROUP BY refcell;

                                                                                                                                QUERY PLAN

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=4697558.19..4697560.69 rows=200 width=64) (actual time=5569.104..5573.877 rows=14 loops=1)
   Group Key: ref.refcell
   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
   Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
   CTE ref
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..27522.76 rows=1000000 width=64) (actual time=197.172..199.926 rows=2936 loops=1)
           ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5022.77 rows=1000000 width=16) (actual time=197.167..198.989 rows=2936 loops=1)
                 ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=197.164..198.240 rows=2936 loops=1)
                       ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=194.764..194.765 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=4102904.80..4125585.42 rows=108890000 width=40) (actual time=5568.535..5573.854 rows=14 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (ref.node = filtered.cell)
         Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
         ->  CTE Scan on ref  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=64) (actual time=197.173..197.334 rows=2936 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=4102632.57..4102632.57 rows=21778 width=24) (actual time=5371.307..5376.075 rows=14 loops=1)
               Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 257kB
               Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
               ->  Subquery Scan on filtered  (cost=4102197.01..4102632.57 rows=21778 width=24) (actual time=5371.209..5376.066 rows=14 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4102197.01..4102414.79 rows=21778 width=24) (actual time=5371.207..5376.062 rows=14 loops=1)
                           Group Key: data.cell
                           Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 793kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=23504.50..4100271.86 rows=385030 width=16) (actual time=2286.179..5368.528 rows=49557 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (data.cell = ref_1.node)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
                                 ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..4071462.50 rows=770059 width=16) (actual time=2281.522..5285.847 rows=753398 loops=1)
                                       Workers Planned: 2
                                       Workers Launched: 2
                                       Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
                                       ->  Parallel Seq Scan on data  (cost=0.00..3993456.60 rows=320858 width=16) (actual time=2258.752..5282.661
rows=251133 loops=3)
                                             Filter: ((ses = ANY ('{0}'::integer[])) AND (event_time >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with ti
me zone) AND (event_time <= '2023-02-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (yas = ANY ('{0,1,2}'::integer[])))
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 67329851
                                             Buffers: shared hit=15515 read=2288426
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=22502.00..22502.00 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=4.643..4.644 rows=2936 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 4096 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 170kB
                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=22500.00..22502.00 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=4.071..4.289 rows=2936 loops=1)
                                             Group Key: ref_1.node
                                             Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 385kB
                                             ->  CTE Scan on ref ref_1  (cost=0.00..20000.00 rows=1000000 width=32) (actual time=0.002..3.427 rows=
2936 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.262 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 51
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 3.719 ms, Inlining 73.689 ms, Optimization 176.614 ms, Emission 109.112 ms, Total 363.134 ms
 Execution Time: 5576.688 ms
(45 rows)
```

5 seconds do not sound very much when I consider it is 200M data, still trying to figure out a way to make it faster, maybe some intermediary table is good too but there need to be filtering to the `yas` and `ses` data so I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the whole ask but couldn't you run h3_polygon_to_cells once offline and not on every query?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why didn't you chose to work with a PostGIS native Hexagon Grid?, e.g. `SELECT cell, count(*) 
FROM data
JOIN (SELECT * FROM ST_HexagonGrid(0.01,ST_MakeEnvelope(28.93155097961426, 40.97555652808213,29.058237075805668, 41.029513890837386,4326))) h ON
  ST_Contains(h.geom,cell)
WHERE 
  "eventDate" BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-01' AND
  "ses" = ANY(ARRAY[0]) AND
  "yas" = ANY(ARRAY[0,1,2])
GROUP BY cell;` Perhaps you could elaborate on why you chose H3 over PostGIS. cheers and +1 for the query!

Comment: `WITH h (hexcell) AS (
  SELECT (ST_HexagonGrid(0.01,ST_MakeEnvelope(28.93155097961426, 40.97555652808213,29.058237075805668, 41.029513890837386,4326))).geom
)
SELECT cell, count(*) 
FROM data
JOIN h ON ST_Contains(h.hexcell,cell)
WHERE 
  "eventDate" BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-02-01' AND
  "ses" = ANY(ARRAY[0]) AND
  "yas" = ANY(ARRAY[0,1,2])
GROUP BY cell;`

Comment: If you're interested, I posted something on grids some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68300557/2275388

Comment: The time taken by JIT is unlikely to be worthwhile.  Turn jit off.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, h3_polygon_to_cells has nothing to do with the slow query times, I also been using postgis for over 2 years now but I was not aware there was a hexagon grid, we used h3 so I just installed it's library into postgis. I will check it thanks!

Comment: @GuvenDegirmenci you're right, h3 isn't the issue here. I just wanted to understand why you use it. I've seen too many people using it just because of the hexagon grid thing... and PostGIS has it since 3.1. Cheers

Comment: I added new details to post according to details of EXPLAIN ANALYZE, I will be doing some experimenting with postgis hexgrids. I am still trying to figure out how postgres indexes are working.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches here, use a different plan shape, or make the existing plan faster.

### Use a different plan shape

Looking at your latest plan, you are kicking the index "data_ses_cell" 750,827 times and doing so takes up most of your execution time. But it thought it would kick it only 200 times.  If it correctly knew how often it would have to kick the index, maybe it would have decided to preprocess the data from "data" into a hash table in wholesale and then use a Hash Join, rather that kicking the index retail in a Nested Loop.

Unfortunately I don't know of any way to fix the estimate of the bottom HashAgg.  200 is the default estimate the planner uses when it has no idea how many groups there is going to be coming out of an Aggregate, but it still needs to pick a number.

You can probably force it to use the Hash Join just by setting enable_nestloop=off.  But to make that efficient, you would likely need a different index.  You want it to quickly apply all the conditions you have other than "cell", since "cell" is what will end up driving the hash table so that would no longer be a condition of the index scan. So you would want an index like `("ses", "yas","eventTime","cell")`.  The inclusion of "cell" as the last column should enable an index-only scan.

If you get it to use this plan with the enable_nestloop=off and the new index, and it is faster, then you have not-very-desirable answer and you know what to investigate (the 200 rows estimate) to turn it into a desirable one.

### Make the existing plan faster

The culprit index scan had to access (8999147+304826)/750827 = 12.4 buffers for every time through the loop.  That is a lot, and it is not clear why.  One possibility is that there are a lot of entries in the index which fail the "eventTime" condition and so get removed but only after accessing some buffers in order to investigate them.  But this doesn't really make sense, as in that case you would expect "Rows Removed by Filter" to be much larger, like around 8 rather than 0 (because one iteration of a index scan returning 0 or 1 row is usually expected to access only about 4 buffers, 3 for descending the index and one for consulting the table).  The only other things I can think of to explain this is that the index is stuffed full of pointers to obsolete tuples.  Then the pointers must be followed to the table pages (leading to buffer accesses) but the rejected rows are not counted as "Removed by Filter" because they were instead removed by visibility checks, not by a filter.

If the "eventTime" condition is removing a lot of tuples but they aren't getting counted in "Rows Removed by Filter" (for reasons I don't understand), then a solution would be add "eventTime" to the existing index as the final column, which allows those rows to get removed without needing to consult the table.  On the other hand if you have a lot of obsolete tuples in the index, the solution would be to make sure you have no long-lived transactions open, and then VACUUM the table immediately before running the query again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions. I have made a few modifications according to your comment and also there have been a few changes to the column names etc. Looks like that index made a lot of difference, but new challenge is to do it with 200M rows now. I am still learning to identify issues by looking at the `EXPLAIN` output and this answer definitely helps, thanks! I hope I can make it even faster.